# Get Snowflake Warehouse details from a Table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to query Warehouse and its properties (size, type, policy, auto suspension time etc.) from a table. Need this info to be able to easily write a monitoring process.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to get properties in tabular format:

[SHOW WAREHOUSES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-warehouses.html)

```
SHOW WAREHOUSES;

-- if additional processing of the output of SHOW command is required
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

Comment: If the user do not have usage/monitor/modify permission on a warehouse, but the user has read access on snowflake.account_uage.views - what will be a good solution.

Comment: @DinakarUllas [WAREHOUSE_EVENTS_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_events_history.html) may be useful to infer some of the details

Comment: WAREHOUSE_EVENT_HISTORY does not give all the details that 'SHOW WAREHOUSES' provides.